# Rails with real time notifications architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, websocket, actioncable

I need to add realtime notifications to my Rails app. Here are the different possible architectures I have found.

#### 1. Rails + Socket.io + Redis: As suggested in this [post](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/02/27/adding-real-time-to-a-restful-rails-app/), having the following architecture:

[image: Rails + Socket.io + Redis]

- **Pro**: Clean, no data is lost if Socket.io is down
- **Con**: Introduces several technologies (hardens maintainability)

#### 2. Rails + Socket.io: Making Rails a Socket.io client, as this repo seems to do: https://github.com/lyondhill/socket.io-ruby-client

[image: Rails + Socket.io]

- **Pro**: Straightforward
- **Con**: Relying on a unpopular library

#### 3. Ruby Faye: http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html

- **Pro**: 100% Ruby
- **Con**: Since an external app is required, Socket.io is much more an industry standard than Faye right now.

#### 4. ActionController::Live: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html

- **Pro**: The Rails in app way
- **Con**: Too immature

Questions:

- Is there a standard way (I'd have missed) to do that nowadays?
- Any thoughts on my comparison (hope this doesn't get closed)?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at eventmachine and websockets. There are also third party services such as Pusher and PubNub that will handle the websocket part for you via HTTP API.

https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket

Rails 5 will also be adding ActionCable which will do this in rails, but it's not out yet.

I would say the advantage to these approaches is that you don't need a separate node.js app. The services are very easy to use but not free.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely take a look on https://github.com/rails/actioncable

Action Cable seamlessly integrates websockets with the rest of your Rails application. It allows for real-time features to be written in Ruby in the same style and form as the rest of your Rails application, while still being performant and scalable. It's a full-stack offering that provides both a client-side JavaScript framework and a server-side Ruby framework. You have access to your full domain model written with ActiveRecord or your ORM of choice.

Comment: "Action Cable is currently considered alpha software."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) (It's my own pet project, so I might be biased).

Although it can also be used as an independent framework, it's easy to set it up either as a Rails add-on or as a socket.io replacement with Redis.

You can write a Plezi websocket controller and have it run together with your your Rails app on the same process (same ip:port) if you switch your server to Plezi's preferred server (just remove references to other servers from your gemfile).

Another alternative is to run Plezi as an independent process (on a different port) and sync them using Redis (using Plezi's Placebo API).

There's a section in Plezi's documentation titled: "[Using Plezi with our existing Rack application](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app)"

**Pro**: Uses native websocket implementations (server side websockets) and a fast C extension server (Iodine). Total integration with your Rails app is possible (serve both websockets and HTTP on the same domain/process/ip/port); Easy scaling (auto-redis support).

**Con**: Young; Requires C extension support (Ruby MRI) and Linux / BSD / OS X machine (no windows); Shared code needs to be thread-safe (websockets might be running in parallel with HTTP or other connections).

Good Luck!

Comment: I'll give it a look, but you should have mentionned upfront that you are the developper of the project!

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger - Sorry, I sometimes forget to mention it's my pet project... I'll fix my answer now.